# Next.js build to HTML does not execute useEffect code

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I am using Next app router to generate a static site. I have a 'client' component that uses useEffect to render KaTeX equation, but when I `npm run build` the component does not render, and when I inspect the HTML only an empty span is render but not the content. I suspect that `useEffect` does not even run once during static site generation. Does anyone know a fix?

```
'use client'
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import katex from 'katex'
import 'katex/dist/katex.min.css'

export default function TeX({ equation, display }: { equation: string, display: boolean }) {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current) {
            katex.render(equation, ref.current, {displayMode: display});
        }
    }, [equation]);
    return (
        <span ref={ref} />
    )
}
```

Comment: One of the first rule of React/Next is that a component is bound to its State. A ref provided by `useRef` can be used to modify properties of the dom element of a component, but it just can not trigger render. You have to use a State (`useState` hook)

Comment: I can provide you with some code, if you need help on that

Comment: @JulienDuris Sure that would be awesome

Comment: Could you tell me more about what `katex.render` is supposed to do to `ref.current` ?

Comment: @JulienDuris I am not sure, but katex.render is supposed to take a string for the equation, together with the html element where the render should happen.

Comment: Ok. Got curious and now starting a new react project with `katex` as dependency to understand what is going on :) hang on a bit

Comment: Actually, dont need the whole state lifecycle. Your code works on my end (I think https://ibb.co/pn7n6GK)

Comment: @JulienDuris Oh does it work for react app? My next app just render the empty span, weirdly

Comment: How did you generate a static web site? What did you do exactly?

Comment: @AhmetFiratKeler I did this static export  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports

Answer (score 0):

Works fine to me, with nextjs. Started fresh with `npx create-next-app@latest`:

page.tsx

```
import TeX from './katex'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <TeX equation="f(a,b,c) = (a^2+b^2+c^2)^3" display={true} />
  )
}
```

katex.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import katex from 'katex'
import 'katex/dist/katex.min.css'

export default function TeX({ equation, display }) {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current) {
            katex.render(equation, ref.current, {displayMode: display});
        }
    }, [equation]);
    return (
        <span ref={ref} />
    )
}
```

To make this work as a static web page:

- add `output: "export"`, in `next.config.js`
- `npm run build`
- `npx serve@latest out`

Comment: I find that this code renders properly when you `npm run dev` but when you `npm run build` to a static export it does not work https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports

Comment: Works to me, when building a static page. The steps I followed: added `output: "export"` in next.config.js => `npm run build` => `npx serve@latest out`

Comment: This is interesting, when you npx serve it does work, but when I try double clicking the html file it does not render. Also when I upload the output html to my server it does not work as well, do you any insight into why this might be?

Comment: I think it has to do with serving the file using a server (such as `npx serve`) will resolve all the links and sources properly, while opening the file directly will use the filesystem of the machine.